# How to navigate across several windows with wxPython?

Tags: navigation, wxpython

I would like to create an application with wxpyhton containing nine windows.

There are either a next or a back button on each window which permit the user to navigate to the following or preceeding window.

Only one window is displayed at once.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the [wxpython demo at the download page](http://wxpython.org/download.php) for your version of python/wxPython. It has two examples how to use the wxPython class `wx.Wizard` made extra for this purpose.